# SQL Server running totals (sum over order by)

Tags: sql-server, sum

I was looking up "running totals" for SQL Server. Easy query. So I wrote this:

```
SELECT 
    firstname, lastname, thetot, 
    SUM(thetot) OVER (ORDER BY lastname) AS runningtot 
FROM 
    customers
```

You'd think an accurate running total would be the output. Not necessarily true. Here's what it spit out:

```
firstname   lastname    thetot  runningtot

Billy       BobThornton 0.01    4.46
Billy       BobThornton 4.45    4.46
Bob         Hope        3.52    7.98
Jimmy       Johnson     4.84    12.82
Jason       Meyers      3.50    16.32
Ted         Turner      1.77    18.09
```

Is it just me or should the first record's running to be `0.01`?

Comment: You need some sort of incremental field to order on, like a date or a unique identifier that represents entry order.

Comment: This could be caused by the fact that the column you are sorting on isn't unique. Try adding another (possible unique) column to the `order by` to break ties.

Comment: Btw: Postgres and Oracle behave in exactly the same way.

Comment: This is actually caused by the defaults SQL uses and aren't (very well) explained. If you don't specify `RANGE/ROWS` but do use an `ORDER BY`, then `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is used, which explains the first 2 being the same. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The self answer you provided drastically changes the semantics.

In the question you are calculating the running total as ordered by firstname, arbitrarily switching to order by PK brings back a resultset that answers an entirely different question.

The reason for the resultset that you are seeing is documented [in books online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx?)

> If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE
>   UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window
>   frame.

The semantics of `RANGE` are that values tied with the same `ORDER BY` value will always be included in each other's window frame.

One way around this that is compatible with the original semantics would be to add a tie breaker to the `ORDER BY` that ensures uniqueness - and thus that ties can never occur.

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname,
       thetot,
       SUM(thetot) OVER (ORDER BY lastname, pk) AS runningtot
FROM   customers
```

**However this is not the best performing method.**

As discussed in [Aaron Bertrand's running total comparison](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) the implementation of `RANGE` is less well performing than that for `ROWS`.

Moreover `ROWS` behaves as you were expecting anyway.

```
SELECT firstname,
       lastname,
       thetot,
       SUM(thetot) OVER (ORDER BY lastname ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS runningtot
FROM   customers
```

Would return

```
| firstname |    lastname | thetot | runningtot |
|-----------|-------------|--------|------------|
|     Billy | BobThornton |   0.01 |       0.01 |
|     Billy | BobThornton |   4.45 |       4.46 |
|       Bob |        Hope |   3.52 |       7.98 |
|     Jimmy |     Johnson |   4.84 |      12.82 |
|     Jason |      Meyers |    3.5 |      16.32 |
|       Ted |      Turner |   1.77 |      18.09 |
```

Or possibly

```
| firstname |    lastname | thetot | runningtot |
|-----------|-------------|--------|------------|
|     Billy | BobThornton |   4.45 |       4.45 |
|     Billy | BobThornton |   0.01 |       4.46 |
|       Bob |        Hope |   3.52 |       7.98 |
|     Jimmy |     Johnson |   4.84 |      12.82 |
|     Jason |      Meyers |    3.5 |      16.32 |
|       Ted |      Turner |   1.77 |      18.09 |
```

anyway (it is undeterministic which row will appear first in the presence of ties)